# How do I get Bootstrap modal with data-remote to work when the page uses https?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, https, modal-dialog

I'm using bootstrap modal with data-remote. The url in data-remote is a relative link, but the remote request fails on pages with https: "The page at [this page] was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://thedomain.com/the/relative/url/in/my/file: this content should also be loaded over HTTPS."

Why doesn't bootstrap load the relative url with https, like the page it's on? How should I fix this?

Comment: The `remote` option is being deprecated, so you might as well not use it in the first place.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using the 'href' and 'data-target'

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this by specifying the full path, not just the relative path.